# Why don't crypt() results match?

Tags: php, authentication, crypt

So basically here's the deal - I've been working on a user creation script that uses php crypt, but I've been having some issues with comparative tests.

Any thoughts?

EDIT:

```
<?php

$pw = 'jason';
$pw2 = 'jason';

$p1 = crypt($pw);
$p2 = crypt($pw2);

if($p1 != $p2){

        echo "oh shoot";

}else{

echo "verified";


}


?>
```

And this consistently replies "oh shoot" indicating that the two outputs do not match.

Comment: Since you evaluated `$password = crypt($password)`, that means `crypt($password)` is really `crypt(crypt('password'))`, which is different from `crypt('password')`.

Comment: hi @Kaz sorry, i didn't make my post very clear. Could you take a look at my updated script and see if it makes more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the function `string crypt ( string $str [, string $salt ] )`
 in php manual [crypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)

> If no salt is provided, PHP will auto-generate either a standard two
>   character (DES) salt, or a twelve character (MD5), depending on the
>   availability of MD5 crypt().

If not provided, one will be randomly generated by PHP each time you call this function. So when you called `crypt` twice, different results returned.

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you Larry!

Answer (score 0):

[Crypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) is a One Way string hashing function.

The "one way" means that it's nearly impossible to derive the original text from the encrypted string.A one-way hash function is designed in such a way that it is hard to reverse the process, that is, to find a string that hashes to a given value.So crypt() generally gives different output for a same string.

If you want to verify your password what you can do is:

```
<?php
$hashed_password = crypt('mypassword'); // let the salt be automatically generated

if (hash_equals($hashed_password, crypt($user_input, $hashed_password))) {
echo "Password verified!";
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi Pritesh, 
Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately I am using an older version of php so hash_equals is not available. Larry's reply above is more appropriate.